# Android: How to pre-populate the photo for a new contact?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm creating a new contact by launching a "new contact" intent like so:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT);
    intent.setType(ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_TYPE);
    intent.putExtra(..., ...);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Does anyone know how I can pre-populate the Photo field in this case?
Since API level 11 I can use [ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.html#DATA)
to pass the photo in the intent's extras, but I also need to support earlier versions.

If you know a workaround, that would also help. One way that I know of to work around it is to create the contact manually first (with the photo set) and then launch an "edit contact" intent, but I would prefer not to do that if there are better options.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.DATA is designed to insert multiple data items, and as you note, it's not available in platforms prior to 11.

What's the use case for pre-populating the photo?

Comment: You can insert the photo as one of the items. Here's the code I use:


            `ContentValues row = new ContentValues();`
            `row.put(ContactsContract.Contacts.Data.MIMETYPE, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);`
            `row.put(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Photo.PHOTO, byteArray);`
            `data.add(row);`

            `intent.putParcelableArrayListExtra("data", data);`